# Incorrect View Hierarchy: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, view, hierarchy, iad, rootview

I've been receiving a warning that is related to my use of the GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController and the BannerViewController for iAd. That warning is:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <RootViewController: 0x14cd143c0>
```

What is wrong with the sequence of code shown below that causes this warning?

In AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow            *window;
RootViewController  *viewController;
}
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application {

    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [window addSubview: viewController.view];
}
```

Then when the user presses a Play button on my home screen, I first open the game center view controller as follows (notice the 2nd line is setting presentingViewController equal to the rootViewController that was set up in the appDelegate):

```
AppDelegate * theAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.presentingViewController = theAppDelegate.viewController;
GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
[presentingViewController presentViewController: mmvc animated: YES completion:nil];
```

After the above code runs, a new scene is loaded. This scene is described in my GameSelectionLayer.h as follows:

```
@interface GameSelectionLayer : CCLayer <InAppStoreControlLayerDelegate> {
    ...
    RootViewController *viewController;
    AppDelegate *app;
    BannerViewController *bannerViewController;
}
```

Then in my GameSelectionLayer.mm, I load the bannerViewController onEnter as follows:

```
-(void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];

    app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    viewController = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];

    bannerViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    app.window.rootViewController = bannerViewController;
}
```

I receive the above mentioned warning when the above code runs. Please let me know what you think I might be doing wrong that is causing this warning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are replacing the view hierarchy of a view controller which has another view controller presented. The "detached" warning comes when you try to present a view controller from a view controller which is not attached to a window, or does not have a descendent view controller attached to a window.

Here I recommend two approaches. Either dismiss all view controllers before replacing the root view controller, or, the better of the two options, use another window with its own root view controller hierarchy.

Also, note that you should not add the view controller's view as a subview of the window. The system does it for you when you set the view controller as the root view controller.

Comment: So, the view controllers are a bit mysterious to me. I think you are saying that my error is in the method "onEnter". How would you suggest implementing your 2nd option? What do you mean by using another window with its own root view hierarchy?

Comment: It means creating a new `UIWindow` object, **retaining it** (it's important!), setting the `rootViewController` property to the view controller you want to display, and calling `makeKeyAndVisible` on the new window.

Comment: Within the "onEnter" method shown in my question, I've created a new UIWindow and retained it. I've set the rootViewController property to the view controller I want to display (namely the bannerViewController), and I made the new window keyAndVisible. This crashes because I am making the rootViewController a child of the bannerViewController. In other words, I deleted the last line of "onEnter" and added the following lines: 
 window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window setRootViewController:bannerViewController];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: You should add it as a child. You should have it standalone on its own window.

Comment: Add what as a child of what? Again, I have deleted the last line of "onEnter" and added the following lines: window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; [window setRootViewController:bannerViewController]; [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I'm sorry, a typo. "shouldn't".

Comment: yes, I got that based on the crash message. What is it that I am doing that is adding the rootViewController as a child of the bannerViewController? Which of my lines of code is in error or what do I need to add?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps because you are trying to present the menu view controller from anther. You should display it in the window and that's it.